# How can I append json to my array in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview, object

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/jsondecodable/courses")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let appData = try JSONDecoder().decode([App].self, from: data)
            print(appData)

        } catch let err {
            print("Err", err)
        }

    }.resume()
```

This is how I parsed the json. But I want to add those parsed data to my array to use it to populate mytableview.

```
struct App: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

var apps = [App]()
```

This is what I get after printed the appData in my console.

> [CustomTableView.App(id: 1, name: "Instagram Firebase"),
>   CustomTableView.App(id: 2, name: "Podcasts Course"),
>   CustomTableView.App(id: 3, name: "Intermediate Training Core Data"),
>   CustomTableView.App(id: 4, name: "Kindle Basic Training")]

Can you help me to understand this concept because I'm new in iOS and searched a lot to find the answer. Thank you so much

This is my whole code

[image]

Comment: `apps.append(contentOf: appData)` just after the `print(appData)`? But you might want to do a `tableViewreloadData()` also, and do that in Main Thread.

Comment: you have to know the basics of json parsing here it is, go through this you will get clarification    https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will search more to learn basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.apps = appData
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**OR**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.apps.append(contentsOf:appData)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

add :

```
self.apps = appData
```

right under  `print(appData)`